# Append button to default layout in django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I want to write my form helper for multiple forms. All the fields are correctly rendered by default layout, the only change I want to make is to add submit button on the end like this:

```
class MyFormHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        // Other initialization code here
        self.layout = Layout(
            // default, inherited layout here
            Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary')
        )
```

However I don't know if there is any way to explicitly build the default layout. I know I can explicitly specify all fields to be rendered in layout, however I don't want to couple the form helper to one form.

I also tried

```
        self.layout.append = Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary')
```

But `self.layout` seems to be `None` at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `add_input` method of `FormHelper`. [See the code here, lines 153 and 275](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/helper.py).

```
class MyFormHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        // Other initialization code here
        self.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary'))
```